# Use Config as generic

Tags: pallet

I have [declared](https://github.com/DigitaIAM/nae-substrate-node/blob/main/pallets/nae/src/lib.rs#L23) `pub struct Change<T: Config> {` at my pallet. Hand made
`impl<T: Config> Clone for Change<T> {` works fine, but when I'm adding `#[derive(Clone)]` to `struct Change` compiler raise errors:

```
cargo build -r
   Compiling nae-node-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/Users/dmitriyshabanov/Projects/nae/nae-substrate-node/runtime)
   Compiling pallet-nae v0.1.0-dev (/Users/dmitriyshabanov/Projects/nae/nae-substrate-node/pallets/nae)
error[E0599]: the method `clone` exists for struct `BoundedVec<Change<T>, <T as pallet::Config>::MaxChanges>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
   --> pallets/nae/src/lib.rs:149:26
    |
23  |     pub struct Change<T: Config> {
    |     ---------------------------- doesn't satisfy `Change<T>: Clone`
...
149 |             for change in changes.clone() {
    |                                   ^^^^^ method cannot be called on `BoundedVec<Change<T>, <T as pallet::Config>::MaxChanges>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
    |
   ::: /Users/dmitriyshabanov/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/alloc/src/vec/mod.rs:400:1
    |
400 | pub struct Vec<T, #[unstable(feature = "allocator_api", issue = "32838")] A: Allocator = Global> {
    | ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ doesn't satisfy `Vec<Change<T>>: Clone`
    |
   ::: /Users/dmitriyshabanov/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/fc3fd07/frame/support/src/storage/bounded_vec.rs:42:1
    |
42  | pub struct BoundedVec<T, S>(Vec<T>, PhantomData<S>);
    | ---------------------------------------------------- doesn't satisfy `_: Clone`
    |
    = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `Change<T>: Clone`
            which is required by `BoundedVec<Change<T>, <T as pallet::Config>::MaxChanges>: Clone`
            `Change<T>: Clone`
            which is required by `Vec<Change<T>>: Clone`
help: consider annotating `Change<T>` with `#[derive(Clone)]`
    |
23  |     #[derive(Clone)]
    |

error[E0277]: the trait bound `Change<T>: Clone` is not satisfied
   --> pallets/nae/src/lib.rs:100:34
    |
100 |         MutationAccepted(T::AccountId, BoundedVec<Change<T>, T::MaxChanges>)
    |                                        ^^^^^^^^^^ expected an implementor of trait `Clone`
    |
note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Clone` for `Change<T>`
   --> pallets/nae/src/lib.rs:21:52
    |
21  |     #[derive(Encode, Decode, TypeInfo, MaxEncodedLen, Clone)]
    |                                                       ^^^^^
    = note: 1 redundant requirement hidden
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Clone` for `BoundedVec<Change<T>, <T as pallet::Config>::MaxChanges>`
    = note: this error originates in the derive macro `Clone` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
help: consider borrowing here
    |
100 |         MutationAccepted(T::AccountId, &BoundedVec<Change<T>, T::MaxChanges>)
    |                                        +

error[E0277]: the trait bound `Change<T>: Clone` is not satisfied
   --> pallets/nae/src/lib.rs:135:4
    |
135 |             changes: BoundedVec<Change<T>, T::MaxChanges>
    |             ^^^^^^^ expected an implementor of trait `Clone`
    |
note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Clone` for `Change<T>`
   --> pallets/nae/src/lib.rs:21:52
    |
21  |     #[derive(Encode, Decode, TypeInfo, MaxEncodedLen, Clone)]
    |                                                       ^^^^^
    = note: 1 redundant requirement hidden
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Clone` for `BoundedVec<Change<T>, <T as pallet::Config>::MaxChanges>`
    = note: this error originates in the derive macro `Clone` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
help: consider borrowing here
    |
135 |             &changes: BoundedVec<Change<T>, T::MaxChanges>
    |             +

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0277, E0599.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `pallet-nae` due to 3 previous errors
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
```

Any idea what can be wrong and how to fix?

PS:

```
rustc 1.60.0 (7737e0b5c 2022-04-04)
cargo 1.60.0 (d1fd9fe2c 2022-03-01)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't implement `Clone` for your `Change` struct.

Use the following declaration:

```
    #[derive(Encode, Decode, TypeInfo, MaxEncodedLen, frame_support::CloneNoBound)]
    #[scale_info(skip_type_params(T))]
    pub struct Change<T: Config> {
        /// primary object of relation
        pub primary: ID,

        /// description of relation between primary object and value
        pub relation: BoundedVec<ID, T::MaxContent>,

        /// value before modification
        pub before: Option<Value>,

        /// value after modification
        pub after: Option<Value>,
    }
```

Then your type will implement `Clone`. Be aware that I used the custom `CloneNoBound` derive macro provided by Substrate. You can also use the standard `Clone` from the rust standard library. However, this will require that `T` also implements `Clone`, which is really not required here. Otherwise you can also still implement `Clone` manually:

```
    #[derive(Encode, Decode, TypeInfo, MaxEncodedLen)]
    #[scale_info(skip_type_params(T))]
    pub struct Change<T: Config> {
        /// primary object of relation
        pub primary: ID,

        /// description of relation between primary object and value
        pub relation: BoundedVec<ID, T::MaxContent>,

        /// value before modification
        pub before: Option<Value>,

        /// value after modification
        pub after: Option<Value>,
    }

    impl<T: Config> Clone for Change {
        fn clone(&self) -> Self {
            Self {
                primary: self.primary.clone(),
                relation: self.relation.clone(),
                before: self.before.clone(),
                after: self.after.clone(),
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, that magic do work. Btw, is it rust issue? asking because I do see that `frame_system::Config` is `'static + Eq + Clone`

Comment: Not an issue directly, more like a limitation of the default derive macros.